# Using third-party JavaScript file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JavaScript file which is not written for Node.js. It is actually written by me, but this question may be more understandable if you think of it as a third-party library.

Normally, a Node.js module only exposes the `module.exports` object to external code. This requires the file to be written with Node.js in mind.

However, the file isn't written for Node.js, yet I want to include it into a Node.js module. I can't edit this file, since it will be used later, independently of Node.js.

I imagine I could pull it off by reading the file and calling `eval` on the contents, but is there a better way?

TL;DR

How can I include a .js file into a Node.js module, without rewriting it to use Node.js-specific code like `exports`?

P.S. The reason I want to use it in Node.js is for a few tests before it's deployed elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the code is written on that file. If the file contains a class or a single object then you can do this:

```
(function(global) {

    function MyClass() {


    }

    MyClass.prototype = {
            ...
    };

    if( typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports ) {
        module.exports = MyClass;
    }
    else if ( global ) {
        global.MyClass = MyClass;
    }

})(this);
```

You can modify the global assignment to be a deeper namespace instead if required.

Comment: This is the standard way I see in github projects for files that should work in browser as well as node.js.

Comment: What about for files that should work in other interpreters, like WScript?

Comment: @KendallFrey then it will attach it to the global object in that environment. Unless it supports module.exports, of course.

Comment: `global` is undefined in WScript. I would like this to be available in WScript, so how can I provide compatibility?

Comment: @KendallFrey `global` is locally scoped custom variable I created in that function (it might as well be `asdasd` since it's local), it's passed in the last line `this` which will evaluate to the global object. After that function has executed, you can access it with `this.MyClass` when in global context. You can also use any other global object reference that is available in that environment (`window`, `self`, etc in browsers), but `this` keyword is specified to resolve to the global object when in global scope.

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed that. How stupid of me. So, if I assign my global object to `this.Foo`, and to `module.exports` if it exists, I should be good, right?

Comment: @KendallFrey in environments without module support, you can just say `MyClass` after including that file, and it should work. In environments with module support you will use `require` to get access to it.